# Why doesn't Visual Studio 2010 show me a popup and the location where an exception is thrown when my code throws an exception in the debugger?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception

I remember it used to do this before.

Now it's only a silent print into the output window informing that an exception is thrown.

I know when it can't find the code, it can do this but when I investigate it, the problem code is mine so it should bring me into the offending line immediately at runtime.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default that behaviour only happens if the exception is *unhandled*. You might have an exception handler somewhere that is quietly handling the exception. Note that certain kinds of projects -- like WinForms, for example -- might insert global exception handlers for you, and possibly those are handling the exception.

In the Debug - Exceptions dialog you can say to break in the debugger when the exception is thrown, regardless of whether it is handled or not.

Comment: Thanks Eric, it was the Debug -> Exceptions. I swear I didn't turned them off but they were all empty in the Thrown column. Maybe it was because I imported my color theme into VS. Btw happy thanksgiving :O

Answer (score 2):

Look at Debug->Exceptions... dialog.  You probably have your exception turned off.

Comment: Thanks you mean the "Thrown" column being checked off? Btw this is out of the box VS 2010 ultimate. Didn't change any setting.

Comment: I checked everything there now, it was all empty, thanks you saved my life :O

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when developing on a 64 bit OS when the exception occurs in some event, usually in a form's loading event for example.

As others have mentioned, setting exceptions to "Thrown" in the Exceptions dialog is a quick work around, although this will make Visual Studio stop at EVERY exception, even ones you are properly handing in a Try / Catch block.